# nav's background-color cut when zoom

Tags: html, css, navbar, background-color

Hello everyone i'm new at coding and i need a little help on my nav bar
i used on my css "white-space: nowrap;" to avoid wrapping on my nav bar and when i scroll to the right after that, on my zoomed page the background color is cut

Can you help to put my background colour completyly to the right?
or advice are welcome !
Thank you

[image: Without zoom]

[image: With zoom]

My html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Conférence des directeurs des écoles doctorales de droit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav><ul>
        <li><a href="#">Présentation</li>
        <li><a href="#">Liste des ED</li>
        <li><a href="#">Documents</li>
        <li><a href="#">Liens</li>
        <li><a href="#">Infomations/IP</li>
        <li><input id=search-button type="submit" name="search_button">
            <input id=search-box type="text" name="search_box" placeholder="Rechercher..."></li>
      </ul></nav>

  </body>
</html>
```

> my css

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "Quicksand Light Regular";
    src: url('quicksand_light-webfont.woff');
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkred;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    zoom: 1;
}

nav li {
    font-family: "Quicksand Light Regular";
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 45px;

}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: increase `max-width` under `nav` to more than `100%` to compensate for the `45px right-margin` added by `nav li`

Comment: Also might need to try using the `overflow` css attribute

Comment: i put `max-width : 330%;` same problem but when i added `overflow : auto;`
it worked but the scroll bar was just under the nav bar and not on the bottom of the page

Comment: see my answer about flex boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone found the solution for me
i had to remove `right : 0;`
and add `min-width:100%;`
Thx for everyone

```
nav {
background-color: darkred;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just change `max-width: 100%` to `width: 100%`  in the CSS rule for `nav`

Comment: It was "width: 100%" i just forget to put it back because i thought max-width : 100% will solve the solution

Comment: And that doesn't help? You can try to remove that "zoom: 1" - it doesn't make much sense anyway...

Comment: also, try adding `overflow-x: visible` to `nav`

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't i removed the `zoom: 1`

Comment: You could use `media queries`  to change the font size or something when the screen becomes too small to fit everything

Comment: well can you do any navbar with a list in one row and coloured background who fit all the page when you zoom?
That'all what i ask XD

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexible boxes instead.

The example below changes from using  `ul` and `li`  to using simple `div` elements to create flexboxes that automatically fit into any size space
(see example)

**EDIT**

Changed HTML:

- Removed UL and LI tags
- Replaced `<UL>` with `<div id="menu">`  and replaced `<LI>` with just `<div>`

List of changed CSS Attributes:

- `max-width: 100%` changed to `min-width: 100%`
- renamed `nav` to `#menu`
- added two new rules for `#menu`  (one for flex box, the other just replacing the old `nav` rule)
- renamed `nav li` rule  to `nav div div`  rule
- removed `margin-right: 45px`  from `nav div div` replacing it with `margin-left` and `margin-right` attributes.

---

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Quicksand Light Regular";
  src: url('quicksand_light-webfont.woff');
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkred;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  zoom: 1;
  min-width: 100%;   // notice I changed max-width to min-width
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: horizontal;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

nav div div {
  font-family: "Quicksand Light Regular";
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Conférence des directeurs des écoles doctorales de droit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <nav>
    <div id="menu">
      <div><a href="#">Présentation</div>
        <div><a href="#">Liste des ED</div>
        <div><a href="#">Documents</div>
        <div><a href="#">Liens</div>
        <div><a href="#">Infomations/IP</div>
        <div><input id=search-button type="submit" name="search_button">
            <input id=search-box type="text" name="search_box" placeholder="Rechercher..."></div>
      </div></nav>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at Full Page view after clicking on **Run Snippet**

Comment: The idea of flex is very interesting and i learned from that so thank you!
The think is, the main reason why i had this problem is because i want my nav in one row
i prefer use flexbox in another section

Comment: just change `flex-wrap: wrap`  to `flex-wrap: nowrap`

Comment: I also removed the `display: inline-block`  because it was messing things up with the **flex boxes**

Comment: i just did, and i had the same problem with the background

Comment: I removed the whole `width: 100%`  tag entirely as well as removed a few other bad tags

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mike510a but i want to find the solution of the problem so i can face it
and not findink an alternative witch are really usefull :
Take this for example :

```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8">
>     <title>Test</title>
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">   </head>   <body>
>     <nav>
>       <ul>
>         <li>test1</li>
>         <li>test2</li>
>         <li>test3</li>
>         <li>test4</li>
>         <li>test5</li>
>         <li>test6</li>
>         <li>test7</li>
>         <li>test8</li>
>         <li>test9</li>
>         <li>test10</li>
>       </ul>
>     </nav>
> 
>   </body> </html>
```

And the css :

```
> nav {   position: absolute;   background-color: blue;   width: 100%;  
> text-align: center;   white-space: nowrap; } li {   display:
> inline-block; }
```

I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I tried including min-width with "max-content" as its value in the body tag. And, it worked